# Send data to controller if item changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0

I need to send to controller only those items that was changed by user. For example if first item `Jhon` changed to `Jhon1` it should send, if it changed one more time to 'Jhon' it does not send. How to check this conditions? Use JQuery? For?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: senddata">send</button>


<script>
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.items.push({ name: 'Jhon' });
    self.items.push({ name: 'Smith' });

    self.senddata = function () {
        var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(self.items());
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Home/ConvertLogInfoToXml',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ jsonOfLog: jsonOfLog }),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        debugger;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string ConvertLogInfoToXml(string jsonOfLog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jsonOfLog);
        return Convert.ToString(jsonOfLog);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, isn't a possibility to perform this verification on server side? If you send just the json data it shouldn't bee a lot of data right? My preference to do it on server side is mostly about the security.

Comment: For example on servere side i should get old items from database to check them with new items. I think it would be additional load on server. Is'n it?

Comment: Definitely will be, but it's a kind of trade off that you should to decide according your system security requirements. I've been working on financial industry for 10 years and this kind of trade off is very acceptable (actually it is required).